# i want to get the text form the h4 tag

Tags: javascript

How to get the text value from

```
<div   style="margin-top:15px;"   class="shortHeader"   id="someid">
  <div>
    <h4 id="someidvalue">text</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

**i have tried with the below code and it says undefined:**

```
document.getElementById("someid").getElementsByTagName("div")[0]
        .getElementsByTagName("h4")[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: Have you tried just following `document.getElementById("someidvalue").innerHTML` ?

Comment: Your code works [**fine here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vynsq/)!!!

Comment: yes i tried and it says say undefined

Comment: Thanks cryoticous .. it worked now..

Answer (score 1):

You can use innerHTML

```
document.getElementById("someidvalue").innerHTML
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/5bUg4/

Comment: i tried with document.getElementById("someidvalue").innerHTML it says undefined

Comment: This should work. Can you send somehow full code? where you try to add a script?

Comment: Good to hear about. Also if you use JQuery you can do like this $('#someidvalue').text(), DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/5bUg4/1/ . And do not forget to mark answere as accepted. :) Thaks

Answer (score 0):

**You can do like this:**

```
 var data=document.getElementById("someidvalue").innerHTML
 console.log(data);
```

Check in console..whether you are getting correct data

Answer (score 0):

While all the document.getElementById posts should work fine I just wanted to provide you with an alternative for more recent browsers that will allow you to be very specific about your selection.

```
var text = document.querySelector("#someid div h4").innerHTML;
alert(text);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7HPDw/)

Answer (score 0):

An H4 element may contain markup, e.g.

```
<h4>Jones, Smith, <em>et al</em></h4>
```

So if you want the markup use innerHTML. However, if you want just the text and that of any child element, use the W3C *textContent* or IE *innerText* property based on a simple test:

```
var element = document.getElementById("someidvalue");
var text = element.textContent || element.innerText || '';
```

If you are not certain that *element* exists, test for it first:

```
var text = element && element.textContent || element.innerText || '';
```

so text will either be null if no element was found or a (possibly empty) string;